# Finding any elliptic curve equation over any field based on order

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves

I am looking for a way to find examples of elliptic curves that will have an order that I have been given. The field size cannot be equal to the given order and it needs to work for large numbers. Is it possible to have a generic calculation that could do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at Section 4 in [this paper](http://bjarkiholm.com/publications/Holm_2005_partiii-essay.pdf) by Holm for a couple of ways of doing this.